# Console data in PHP laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dump, dd

Following is my code of the controller. I'm calling this controller, but still unable to do any console. Am I doing anything wrong here? I just want to observe values in console, functionality is working fine.

```
public function registerValidation(Request $request)
    {
        dd("request 2");
        var_dump("request 2");
        dump("request 2");
        dd($request);
        var_dump($request);
        dump($request);
        die("here");
        $this->validate(
            $request,
            [
                'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
                'password_confirmation' => 'required',
                'termsconditions' => 'required',
            ]
        );
    }
```

Comment: What console are you talking about, the browser's Javascript Console? Or the "terminal"/CLI?

Comment: @kerbholz I'm talking about browser Javascript console.

Comment: Why would you expect a server-side, non-javascript code to output anything to the client's js console?

Comment: @kerbholz from where can I see these logs then?

Comment: What logs? Laravel's logs are stored in the `storage/logs` folder of your project

Comment: @kerbholz I'm talking about `$request`, how can I store that in logs?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging Good luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213764/discussion-between-knowledge-seeker-and-kerbholz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dd` is short for dump and die, and will stop execution of your code.

You're probably looking for `var_dump()` if you're running your code in console, or `error_log()` if you're using your site in a browser, and watching the logs (with something like `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`).

Comment: `var_dump()` & `error_log()` are also not working and not giving any value in the console

Comment: `error_log()` logs errors to the error logs. Are you watching the error logs, or are you looking at stdout in a terminal?